# Hibernate query - ClassCastError

Tags: java, hibernate

```
"select c.type, c.date, sum(c.amount) from CustomerPayment c  where c.date  like '%" + year + "' and c.type='Cash'"
```

Above hibernate query gives ClassCastError because of my select statement.

How can i write it in proper way? Do need to use criteria for summation? What is the y good for above query? I'm confused.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to CustomerPayment
    at tekirmobile.clController.getTotalCash(clController.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
```

I get these error because of above query

Answer (score 1):

you are selecting three properties: `c.type`, `c.date` and `sum(c.amount)`, this means each result will be a Object[], containing each of the three selected properties. You can't cast this to CustomerPayment.

If CustomerPayment has a compatible constructor, you could do something like

```
select new CustomerPayment(c.type, c.date and sum(c.amount)) ...
```

or you could potentially do something like

```
"select c, c.type, c.date, sum(c.amount) from CustomerPayment c ... "

Object[] result = query.uniqueResult();
CustomerPayment payment = (CustomerPayment) result[0];
```

But, then I'm not sure what you need the sum for though, you aren't using the sum anywhere in the where clause. Its a bit unclear what you are trying to accomplish. As in, what do you want  the result of the uniqueResult to be? A CustomerPayment instance? or a list of values?

Comment: but i have to select all them to get the proper result

Comment: please try adding the code where you execute the query, and access the result, via .list() or .uniqueResult() :)

Comment: i used uniqueResult() but it still causes problem

Comment: your problem is that you cant cast Object[] to CustomerPayment

Answer (score 0):

Actually it won't return `Object[]` as per another answer. It will return `Object[][]`. Each array of it will consist of an array having 3 entries for `c.type, c.date & sum(c.amount)`.

Refer the following diagram for easy understanding:

```
-----------------------------------
      |    0    |    1    |   2   |
-----------------------------------
  0   | c.type1 | c.date1 |  sum  |
-----------------------------------
  1   | c.type2 | c.date2 |  sum  |
-----------------------------------
  2   | c.type3 | c.date3 |  sum  |
-----------------------------------
```

Let me know the exact requirement of yours so that I can suggest you suitable solution.