# How can I reach my object at arraylist

Tags: java, hibernate

```
  ArrayList<CustomerPayment> cp = null;

    this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();


    try {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("select c.type, c.date, sum(c.amount) from CustomerPayment c  where c.date  like '%" + year + "' and c.type='Cash'");
        cp = (ArrayList<CustomerPayment>)q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(cp.get(0).getAmount()+"");
```

I have above code in function. However;  `System.out.println(cp.get(0).getAmount()+"");` I cannot get my element on in the arraylist like that.

How can I get amount in the object's amount?

Comment: you didn't you continue this in the previous question you opened?

Comment: and as I told you in the previous answer, you aren't selecting any CustomerPayment instances, you are getting each property as a element in a Object array.

Comment: so how can i fix it in right way?

Comment: first. what do you want it to return (i asked this before), a list of values (type, date and sum(c.amount).. or, instances of CustomerPayment?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should have `group by` by some field in your query because you use `SUM`.
Then you can create constructor in `CustomerPayment` with 3 arguments and `select new CustomerPayment(...)` with your arguments.

Comment: i already mentioned that in this answer, I dont think he likes that solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327792/hibernate-query-classcasterror/16327816#16327816 , hence the new question :P any ways, +1 and im off to sleep ;)